# Dependencies for jfxtras

Tags: maven, jfxtras

I am planning to use jfxtras 0.7rc2 version in one of my maven build based projects. What are the dependencies I have to add for this?

I am not sure if this version of jfxtras is available in maven repo's. Thanks for your help.

Regards,
Abi

Answer (score 0):

I guess [this link](http://groups.google.com/group/jfxtras-dev/browse_thread/thread/e8f3819120fcc33b/8e933d5de82e7626) gives you info on how to do this.

As per this, due to licensing reasons the jars/SDK is not available in maven central.  However, you can install it locally and using a maven plugin, deploy it to your local repository as maven artifact.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I guess that link is for building jfxtras..I just want to add jfxtra jar files into my maven repo...